# using dictionary in OrderedDict in Django

Tags: python, dictionary

```
trainer_dict = OrderedDict([('Smith', {'hour_5':'Julia','hour_1':'','hour_2','Kim'}),('Sam',{'hour_5':'','hour_1':'Anna','hour_2',''})])
```

How I use the value of hour_num (Julia, Kim, Anna) in the dictionary?

```
for trainer in trainer_dict:
     trainer.hour_5
```

Above code has an error: 'str' objects has no attribute 'hour_5'.

So, {{ trainer.hour_5}} show nothing in template.

```
for trainer in trainer_dict:
     trainer['hour_5']
```

has also an error: string indices must be integers.

There is a dictionary in [()]. How I access the dictionary??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
for trainer, training in trainer_dict.items():
     training['hour_5']
```

`my_dict = OrderedDict([('foo', {'a':'b'}),('bar',{'c':'d'})])` will create a dict like object which can be represented like this:

```
my_dict = {
    'foo': {'a': 'b'},
    'bar': {'c': 'd'}
}
```

You can iterate over keys, values and key-value pairs of `my_dict` using `my_dict.keys()`, `my_dict.values()` and `my_dict.items()`.

Hope it helps

Comment: It doesn't work. ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2).  So I tried `for trainer, training, etc in trainder_dict:
              training['hour_5'] `  has an error: string indices must be integers.

Comment: @Julia I've updated the answer. Forgot to add .items()

Comment: I think you misspelled 'items' to 'itmes'

Comment: Yes, my mistake. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

When you do `for trainer in trainer_dict` the trainer here is the key in the dict , that is a string (name of the trainer) in your case. So in order to get the value stored at that key you can do `trainer_dict[trainer]` that will give you the the another dict for example `{'hour_5':'Julia','hour_1':'','hour_2','Kim'}` for the name 'Smith'. Make sense?